# Paypal REST API: Retrieve invoice numbers for further processing after payment approved

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I was use this [Paypal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) for my shopping app, after executed and get approved of the buyer's payment, I want to return payment details so that I can continues for further action such as update database.

I get this hit back URL `http://example.com/shopping/payment?success=true&paymentId=PAY-1TK25581J9941930MK2H3ODR&token=EC-9JK21383KS5324308&PayerID=RELUJA6BN3MNE`, in my source code, I have `$info = $payment->getTransactions();` to view payment's details after payment approved, print as `print_r($info)`:

`Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [total] => 56.00 [currency] => GBP [details] => PayPal\Api\Details Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [subtotal] => 46.00 [shipping] => 10.00 ) ) ) ) [payee] => PayPal\Api\Payee Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [email] => myshop@example.com ) ) [description] => Payment description [invoice_number] => 0AGIRVBYCOLK [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [name] => Blossom Cherry [price] => 20.00 [currency] => GBP [quantity] => 1 [description] => Tanks / Womens - M ) ) [1] => PayPal\Api\Item Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [name] => Space Sheep [price] => 26.00 [currency] => GBP [quantity] => 1 [description] => Roundnecks / Mens - L ) ) ) [shipping_address] => PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [recipient_name] => test buyer [line1] => Level 01, Wall Street [city] => ABC City [state] => Manchester [postal_code] => 12345 [country_code] => UK ) ) ) ) [related_resources] => Array ( ) [notify_url] => http://example.com/paypal/pp-ipn.php ) ) )`
`

How can I get each individual elements, let says I want to get `[invoice_number]` for database process in the app?

I have tried `echo $info[0]['invoice_number']` but error shown up, what is the best way to decode above arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the PHP SDK documentation getTransactions() returns an array of objects. So you should be able to access the array of objects like this.

[pseudo code]

```
$transactions = $result->getTransactions();
$transaction = $transactions[0];
$transaction->invoice_number;
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me ... invoice is set on checkout but is not returned on   $result = $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
  $transactions = $result->getTransactions();